# Filter get_categories() for taxonomy term in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to filter my category listing for a taxonomy term.

Only, I have no clue how to accomplish this. Any help would be very welcome.

```
<?php

// $filter = array('region'=>$name);

$categories = get_categories();
foreach ($categories as $cat)
{
    if($cat->parent < 1)
    {
    $cat_name = $cat->cat_name;
    $catid = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );
    echo $cat_name. '<br/>';

    $args=array(
      'orderby' => 'name',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'child_of' => $catid
      );
    $categories=get_categories($args);
      foreach($categories as $category) { 
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a><br/>';
        } 

    }
}

// print_r($categories); 


?>
```

Comment: What is this extra taxonomy term? Is is a category from which you want to show all sub-categories? Or do you only want to show the categories used by all posts that have the custom taxonomy `region` set to `$name`?

Comment: Let's keep the discussion at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4724/filter-get-categories-for-taxonomy-term-in-wordpress/4915

Answer (score 2):

On the version of wordpress I'm using which is version 3.1.2. If you were to add 'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_term' to the array of args it should work. So here's a modification to your original code to include the taxonomy in the array. Don't know the taxonomy name you're trying to use or not though:

```
<?php 

// $filter = array('region'=>$name); 

$categories = get_categories(); 
foreach ($categories as $cat) 
{ 
    if($cat->parent < 1) 
    { 
    $cat_name = $cat->cat_name; 
    $catid = get_cat_ID( $cat_name ); 
    echo $cat_name. '<br/>'; 

    $args=array( 
      'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_term', 
      'orderby' => 'name', 
      'order' => 'ASC', 
      'child_of' => $catid 
      ); 
    $categories=get_categories($args); 
      foreach($categories as $category) {  
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a><br/>'; 
        }  

    } 
} 

// print_r($categories);  
?>
```

Comment: Also take a look at this page:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories